# How to disallow the user to access my home page when not logged in

Tags: php, url

I've searched on many ways to prevent direct url access but none of it, fitted my code. I tried to put

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || $_SESSION['logged-in'] !== true) {

// not logged in, move to login page

header('Location: login.php');

exit;

}
```

that code to verify and to change the page when the user try to access the home page when not logged in. The home page cannot be accessed when not logged in but the problem is even when the username and password is correct, it still goes to login page. What is the problem with the code?

Home page:

```
    <?php
  require 'user.php';
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || empty($_SESSION['logged-in'])){

header('Location:index.php');

exit;

}

?>


<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      You have successfully logged in 

      <?php
session_start();

        $user = $_SESSION['current_user'];

        echo $user->firstname.' '.$user->lastname.'.';
?>



    </p>

    <p>This is your home page.</p>

    <p>Click <a href='update_user.php?username=<?php echo $user->username ?>'>[here]</a> to update user profile.</p>    
    <p>Click <a href='list_user.php'>[here]</a> to see the list of users.</p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

login page

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Enter Username and Password to Login:</p>
    <form action='login_process.php' method='post'>
      <table border='1'>
        <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp</td>
          <td><input type='submit' value='Login'></td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

login process

```
 <?php
  require 'user.php';
?>
<?php
  $user = new User();
  $user->username = $_REQUEST['username'];
  $user->password = $_REQUEST['password'];

  $found = $user->checkLogin();


  if ($found){//redirect to home page
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['current_user']=$user;
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
  }
   else{//invalid username and password
    echo "Invalid username/password.  Click <a href='index.php'>[here]</a> to login again.";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded inside all pages using sessions? If it isn't, **do**. It's required when using sessions.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: This isn't enough code to go on. Try just `if(!isset($_SESSION['logged-in'])){..}` or `if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || empty($_SESSION['logged-in']))` - if you want to destroy the session on logout, that would need to be done if you're not already doing so; and/or unset.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. I'm betting you are outputting before header, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Don't use `$_SESSION`. `$_SESSION` are cookies. A hacker can manipulate his/her cookies to get entrance...

Comment: Well, for one thing, you have `session_start();` twice in `Home page`.

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to `$_SESSION['logged-in']` so that's why your code is failing. Replace it `$_SESSION['current_user']` most likely. Plus your code does show 2 `session_start();` in the question for Home page.

Comment: I already changed it with ['current_user'] but still when the username and password are correct it still redirects to index.php. :(

Comment: We don't know what your `checkLogin()` function does `$found = $user->checkLogin();`, so if it's a DB related function, the query's failing.

Comment: <?php
  require 'user.php';
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['current_user']) || empty($_SESSION['current_user'])){

header('Location:index.php');

exit;

}

?>
that is my updated code, my problem now is that, the user can directly access the home page. :(

Comment: What am I going to use then? @CommuSoft

Comment: Where am I going to put that? @zerkms

Comment: #Jen: you should store the username/password or a hash in the $_SESSION you can do that. And then check manually each time if that user is logged in. otherwise, I could set my cooking `logged-in` to `true` and well, have access.

Comment: Will you please give me an example how to do that? :(

Comment: What do you mean by "home page"? What you are essentially doing, from what I can tell, is making the login page the home page, is that right?  Instead of doing what you are doing, it might be easier to have a page that for non logged in users displays the login but for logged in users displays what you are calling the "home page." (like what @Rasclatt said)  Home page usually means the default page that displays when anyone goes to the domain name with no additions to the url.

Answer (score 1):

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require('user.php'); ?><html>
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><?php
    // You are either logged in or not. If not, let user know to login.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
             You must be logged in to view this content
            <a href="login.php">Click to login</a>
            <?php }
    else {
            $user   =   $_SESSION['current_user'];
            echo $user->firstname.' '.$user->lastname.'.'; ?></p>
    <p>This is your home page.</p>
    <p>Click <a href='update_user.php?username=<?php echo $user->username ?>'>[here]</a> to update user profile.</p>    
    <p>Click <a href='list_user.php'>[here]</a> to see the list of users.</p> 
    <?php } ?>   
</body>
</html>
```

process login

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require('user.php');
    $user           =   new User();
    $user->username =   $_REQUEST['username'];
    $user->password =   $_REQUEST['password'];
    // Validate user
    $found          =   $user->checkLogin();

    if($found == true) {
            //redirect to home page
            $_SESSION['current_user']   =   $user;
            // Assign username to session for check on homepage and elsewhere
            // If not logged in, this session variable should not be set
            // Should be destroyed if user logs out.
            $_SESSION['username']       =   $_POST['username'];
            header("Location: home.php");
            exit;
        }
    //invalid username and password, redirect with login error
    else 
        header("Location: login.php?error=login"); ?>
```

login.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- If error, let user know their login failed-->
<p><?php echo (isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'login')? '<span style="color: red;">Invalid Username/Password.</span> Please try again.':"Enter Username and Password to Login:"; ?></p>
    <form action='login_process.php' method='post'>
      <table border='1'>
        <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp</td>
          <td><input type='submit' value='Login'></td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start()
If Session["user"] == null, redirect to the login page
In the login page, get password using form
Post this form to the login page
Check your authentication service (e.g. a table in mysql) wether the user is authorized
If yes, Session["user"] = $userName, redirect the user to the page. 
If no, prompt for password again
```

Comment: No, i want my user to disallow accessing the home page when not logged in. Will you please give the exact code of what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

1) You dont seem to be assigning any value to $_SESSION['logged_in'], hence your first assertion mighr be returning true. why not check if the 'current_user' is set instead?

2) You are using an exact equality operator (read: !==) at this line:
    $_SESSION['logged-in'] !== true
If it is not (of type boolean and true) or ($_SESSION does not exist) the assertion will always be true, leading to the login page.

3) Have you done a session_start before checking the $_SESSION superglobal? If not the $_SESSION variable will not be populated with anything.

Comment: I already changed the logged_in to current_user. I have a session_start(). What is wrong? :(

Comment: Try a var_dump($_SESSION) on the home page just after session_start() and verify that your variables are what you intend them to be?